# Are some Pig real time use cases available?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Please provide me real time Pig use cases. Banking and healthcare would be of great help. Also curious if Pig can be used as a ETL tool in Hadoop world.

Answer (score 1):

Pig is typically a batch processing tool. But I'm not sure what do you refer for when you ask for "real time Pig use cases".
ETL - basically anything can be used for ETL purpose what can Extract Transform Load pig can do that. We're using it in batch workflows for ETL.

Answer (score 0):

You can find few POC for understaning the Usage of PIG in below link

http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/

Apache Pig is a platform for analyzing large data sets that consists of a high-level language for expressing data analysis programs, coupled with infrastructure for evaluating these programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. awesome examples. Just curious, do by chance do you know what editor is used to write a pig code in real industry? Some say Eclipse with pig plugin and some say HUE. thanks once again

Comment: It depends on company to company we used Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the book entitled "[Pig design patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783285559)" by Pradeep Pasupuleti  for some useful examples (with source code [included](https://github.com/pradeep-pasupuleti/pig-design-patterns))